What's the maximum and minimum value of $P(-2)$?
Consider a quartic polynomial
$$P(x) = ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$$
Where $a, b, c, d, e\in \{0, 1, 2\}$ and $0, 1, 2$ are chosen at least once. What's the maximum and minimum value of $P(-2)$?
If we were to consider instead
$$P(-1) = a-b+c-d+e$$
then to obtain the maximum, we could have maximized $a, c, e$ while minimizing $b, d, e$.
$$P(-2) = 16a - 8b + 4c -2 d + e = 16a + 4c +e - (8b+2d)$$
Choosing $a = c = 2, e = 1, b = 0, d = 0$ leads to $P(-2) = 41$. However, it seems that this isn't really the maximum.

Wouldn't it be easier just to write it as $16a-8b+4c-2d+e$? And then for the maximum, give the top two positive positions $2$s and the negative positions $0$s? For the minimum, do the opposite.

What is the maximum value then? To me, it seems that $41$ is correct.

Your reasoning is correct, the maximum is $41$.
$$P(-2) = 16a - 8b + 4c - 2d + e$$
What we need to do to find the maximum is try to make $a,c,e$ as big as possible and $b,d$ as small as possible. So $b=d=0,a=b=2,e=1$ is correct. Notice how each variable has a "priority" given by the absolute value of its coefficient.

Yes. It might improve the answer to add a demonstration that this is indeed the maximum.
